# Application() of a AAR library

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, aar

I created an AAR library on android and imported it into another project
When I try to execute something from this library, it gives an error saying that Room was not started, I start Room in my Application (),
which leads me to think that the Application () of the AAR library is not being called
How do I get this Application () to start?

Comment: What is "Room"?

Comment: Why have you an `Application` object in your library ? If you really need it, you can override it in your app to initialize the database.

Comment: You're going to have to provide a lot more detail. Take the time to fully explain the interface for the AAR classes, how you're building the application and trying to use it.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any application class in the `android-library` that triggered automatically. You should expose an entry point in your library in order to receive the context and init everything you need from there (for example the Room DB).

Another way (maybe a little bit more complicated) is to create a provider and attach it in the application's lifecycle. Here is an [example](https://github.com/florent37/ApplicationProvider).